# Problem naming the download file

Tags: php

I have some php code which is suppose to download a zip file...this code is called from a file called **download_file.php** (very original, i know)

The relevant function is as follows :

```
function download_clientfile() {
    if ($this->download_file === FALSE) {
        $this->log->log(sprintf("The download file was not generated."), PEAR_LOG_CRIT);
        return;
    }

    $fsize = filesize($this->download_file);
    $path_parts = pathinfo($this->download_file);
    $ext = strtolower($path_parts["extension"]);

    header('Content-Description: File Transfer');
    header('Content-Type: application/octet-stream');
    header('Content-Disposition: attachment; file='.$path_parts['basename']);
    header('Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary');
    header('Expires:0');
    header("Cache-control: must-revalidate, post-check=0, pre-check=0");
    header('Pragma: public');
    header('Content-Length: '.filesize($this->download_file));
    ob_clean();
    flush();
    readfile($this->download_file);
    exit;
```

}

---

Problem : The file downloaded is the zip file that is expected, however its downloaded with the name 'download_file.php'

Any suggestions on how I can get it to download by the name of the zip file.
Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Use *filename* instead of *file*:

```
header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename='.$path_parts['basename']);
```

Also, you may encounter browsers which use the extension anyway. In that case, you can call the script like this:

```
download_file.php?file=myfile.zip
```

or:

```
download_file.php/myfile.zip
```

This way, the URL ends in .zip, which tricks the browser into thinking it is downloading a ZIP file.

Comment: Thank you. At least with Firefox and Chrome, changing to **filename** instead of **file** did the trick.

Answer (score 0):

Try changing file= to filename=

`header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename='.$path_parts['basename']);`

Answer (score 0):

use

```
header("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=\"$filename\"");
```